# Web Services development with Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

Need to develop a web services in Eclipse Helios.This **web services is used by other web applications and android application for accessing data from DB**. Can anybody suggest me any *tutorial or development guide*? I searched in the internet, most of it i saw *they used Axis or Jersey like technologies*. I don't have knowledge in those new technologies. How can I develop?

Answer (score 1):

Jersey is good to develop REST api(Web service). you can find the good tutorial below -

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-tomcat/

Spring MVC is also a good alternate.